# avoid line numbering in a algorithm when closing tcolorbox and adjustbox

Tags: numbering, tcolorbox, algorithms, algorithm2e, adjustbox

when closing the tcolorbox and adjustbox inside an algorithm, the lines of codes corresponding to their commands are displayed numbered. How can I prevent the 1 beside the caption (see the below figure) from being displayed in the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{ float, tcolorbox, adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[htp!]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth} \begin{tcolorbox}[left=20pt] 
\setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}
\KwData{X: some description o fthe data}
\KwData{Y: other data to describe}
\vspace*{5pt}
\hrule
\vspace*{5pt}
here is the first lone of the code \;
\For{ condition }{
    wow for loop!! \;
    \For {condition}{
        \While{condition}{
        that's intriguing;
        \While{indx in indxs or empty}{indx  $\leftarrow$ rblabla\;}}
    blabla\;
    \For{condition}{
      blabla\;
      blabla\;}}}
      %here I should put something to stop the numbering
      \end{tcolorbox}  \end{adjustbox} 
\caption{my caption}\label{alg:this}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: code output]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be sufficient to remove the orphaned line numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tcolorbox, adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \SetNlSty{@gobble}{}{}% Remove line numbering
  \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth}
    \SetNlSty{textbf}{}{}% Default line numbering style
    \setcounter{AlgoLine}{0}% Restore default line numbering start
    \begin{tcolorbox}[left=20pt]
      \KwData{X: some description o fthe data}
      \KwData{Y: other data to describe}
      \vspace*{5pt}
      \hrule
      \vspace*{5pt}
      here is the first lone of the code \;
      \For{ condition }{
        wow for loop!! \;
        \For {condition}{
            \While{condition}{
            that's intriguing;
            \While{indx in indxs or empty}{indx  $\leftarrow$ rblabla\;}}
        blabla\;
        \For{condition}{
          blabla\;
          blabla\;}}}
          %here I should put something to stop the numbering
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{adjustbox} 
  \caption{my caption}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

We set `\NlSty` to `\@gobble` the line numbering outside the `tcolorbox`, and restore it inside. Crude, but functional.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. this works fine!